# Cannot figure out! Lowest number using operator overloading (operator==)

Tags: c++

**This was a programming problem to use operator overloading operator== to find the lowest integer among the 3 integer inputs (You can only edit LINE-1 & LINE-2)**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myClass {
public:
    int data;
    myClass(int x) : data(x) { }
    myClass operator==(myClass &m1) {
        myClass m(0);
        ____________________;    // LINE-1
            return m;
    }
};

void fun(____________________) { // LINE-2
cout << m.data << endl;
}

int main() {
    int i, j, k;
    cin >> i >> j >> k;

    myClass m1(i), m2(j), m3(k);
    fun(m1 == m2 == m3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because: **This was a programming [challenge] problem to use operator overloading operator== to find the lowest integer among the 3 integer inputs..** which, while a horrible reason to use in real code, is exactly what it claims to be.

Answer (score 2):

This is a confusing and convoluted. However, here are some hints. I think it helps to temporarily suspend the (sane  and expected) association of `==` with “equals”. Symbols are names we attach meanings to..

- The (questionable) `==` operator returns a myClass. This is given from the provided (non-standard and confusing) declaration of `myClass operator==(myClass &m1)`.
- The `==` operator (as questionably declared) must return *a* myClass value; this means that LINE-1 must re-assign/alter the `m` that is returned, *or* return early. Consider the use of ternary `?:` operator. While still valid, returning early may cause a compiler warning and/or be “incorrect”, per the “approved answer”.
- The indent following LINE-1 can be ignored, from a parsing viewpoint, although “the approved solution” might involve using a side-effect in an `if` such that the following line is *expected* to be indented. I would ignore the indent and justify the approach.
- The `==` definition can access `this` and member variables, as though it was a method. It would be hard to write a (sane) `==` if this was not the case!
- In LINE-2, the `fun` function must accept the resulting type of calling this (questionable) `==` operator. Refer to the declaration. `fun(m1 == m2 == m3)` is the same as `fun((m1 == m2) == m3)`.
- `fun(m1 == m2 == m3)` is a confusing way to say `fun(m1.lowerOf(m2).lowerOf(m3))`, where lowerOf is a method declared as `myClass lowerOf(myClass& m1)` which looks surprisingly similar to..